# JQuery autocomplete dropdown select function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could you please help me on how to fire a javascript function txtID() on select of an item from autocomplete dropdown

Below is the snippet

```
$("Autotxt").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Webservice.asmx/GetNames",
            data: "{'prefixText':'" + request.term + "'}",
            dataType: "json", 
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.split('|')[0],
                        val: item.split('|')[1]
                    }
                }))
            },

            error: function (result) {
                alert("Due to unexpected errors we were unable to load data");
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("Due to unexpected errors we were unable to load data");

            }
        }).result(function (event, ui) {
            txtID(ui.item.val);
        });
    },

    minLength: 2
});

function txtID(val)
{
alert(val)
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve ? Alert when something is selected in the suggestion menu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `select` event of the autocomplete:

```
$("Autotxt").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        ...
    },
    select: function(e, ui) {
        txtID(ui.item.value);
    }
});
```

[Autocomplete Select Event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select)

Answer (score 0):

1.Your autocomplete can't work because there is no HTML element which is called Autotxt, you either have to provide it with a #Autotxt for ID or a class .Autotxt to select it properly.
2. You have to look how your "suggestion" list is named on which you want to bind the `.on("click",...)` event, to be able to call your function.

Comment: i have the HTML element and i was able to get the suggestionlist. I want fire the below JS function on select of the suggested item which carries a value for further operations.

Comment: Then do the following $('suggestionnlist').on("click",function(){txtID();}); suggestionnlist stands for the name you pretend to know !